# Combinations of substrings that represent original string

Tags: javascript, string, substring, combinations

I'm looking for a method to compute all the substring combinations of a string, that joined represent the original string, so

```
"ice"
```

returns

```
[
   ["i", "c", "e"],
   ["i", "ce"],
   ["ic", "e"]
]
```

It's easy to compute all possible substrings, though I don't know how end up with above like combinations. Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Are you requiring them to be in order? Like ["ie", "c"] would not be a valid combination?

Comment: yes, ["ie", "c"] would not be valid. if you do a .join("") on a result it should equal the input string

Comment: You forgot `["ice"]`.

Comment: i actually don't need the original string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [generating the power set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15649645/1048572) of all possible split positions.

```
string: "ice"; positions: {1,2}

{}        ["ice"]
{1}       ["i", "ce"]
{2}       ["ic", "e"]
{1,2}     ["i", "c", "e"]
```

The code is similar as well:

```
function substringCombinations(str) {
    if (!str.length)
        return [[]];
    var res = [[str.charAt(0)]];
    for (var i=1; i<str.length; i++) {
        var c = str.charAt(i); // for each character
        for (var j=0, l=res.length; j<l; j++) {
            // either generate a new substring
            res.push(res[j].concat([c]));
            // or add it to the last substring
            res[j][res[j].length-1] += c;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

```
> function substringCombinations("ice")
[["ice"],
 ["i","ce"],
 ["ic","e"],
 ["i","c","e"]]
```

Comment: awsome. i bow my forehead to the dust

Comment: as a bonus question: how would you go about modifying above method, to take a parameter n, which is an upper bound on the length of the subset combinations, so substringCombinations("ice",2) returns
[["ice"],["i","ce"],["ic","e"]]

Comment: `if (res[j].length < 2) res.push(res[j].concat([c]));` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest partition numbers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29?

You'd view this problem as the way of adding up numbers denoting the length of substrings to equal the length of the original string.

Example, "ice" = 3, the solutions to your problem is then:

```
3 = 
    3 ("ice")
    2 + 1 (["ic", "e"])
    1 + 2 (["i", "ce"])
    1 + 1 + 1 (["i", "c", "e"])
```

Note the wiki entry considers the combinations as order independent, so part of your answer depends on generating permutations to every combination as well. Also note how quickly this blows up.

Comment: this definitely sounds like an option. can you maybe provide [pseudo-]code for an implementation using above method? and i'm aware that this will be computationally long for longer inputs

Comment: I think you can check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457913/algorithm-to-partition-a-string-into-substrings-including-null-partitions) it's quite similar on what you want to do

Comment: Generating partition numbers can also be recursive as so. I'd look at the above @hsorensen

Comment: i have looked at the recursive python solution, but this gives me a headache, since that solution does not return ".f.o.o.", and I simply dont need the parameter n... still unclear to me what a recursive solution would look liek